# Triggering Vue.js reactivity when adding a new key to an object

Tags: vue.js, vue-reactivity

I am using the following function to add a new key/value pair to an object.

```
                .then(response => {
                    this.plantRegisteredMaterials = response.data.tenantPlantMaterials.edges;
                    this.plantRegisteredMaterials.forEach(plantMaterial => {
                        this.materials.forEach(tenantMaterial => {
                            if (
                                tenantMaterial.node.id ==
                                plantMaterial.node.material.id
                            ) {
                                tenantMaterial.node.isRegistered = true; //This is the new key I want Vue to recognize
                            } else tenantMaterial.node.isRegistered = false; //This is the new key I want Vue to recognize
                        });
                    });
                });
```

This object is used as `items` on a `v-data-table`.

However when I add this new key/value pair to the object, Vue doesn't recognize it and those changes are not detected by the `v-data-table` unless I click on something like `Sort` or anything else that forces the DOM to re-render.

I know there is some way to force Vue to recognize those changes. How Should I do it ?

I tried `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify()` as I have read in some other topics , but it doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue cannot detect adding a new key to an Object. ([source](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects))

You have two options:

1: Add the new key using `this.$set(tenantMaterial.node, 'isRegistered', true)`

2: Fully construct a plain Javascript object before assigning it to the reactive Vue object:

```
const plantRegisteredMaterials = response.data.tenantPlantMaterials.edges

plantRegisteredMaterials.forEach(plantMaterial => {
  // Add, remove, change keys of plantMaterial
  ...
})
this.plantRegisteredMaterials = plantRegisteredMaterials
```

Comment: Yes, perfect , ```this.$set(tenantMaterial.node, 'isRegistered', true)```, works perfectly and the link is very instructive. Thank you ver much

Comment: With Vue3, reactive() supports key addition. A deep watch can also trigger on the addition itself.